# Smaller font sizes in boitecoloriee environment gives bad result

Tags: color, boxes, fontsize, backgrounds

The [boites](http://ctan.org/pkg/boites) package *defines environments that allow page breaks inside framed boxes whose edges may be variously fancy. The bundle includes a few examples (shaded box, box with a wavy line on its side, etc)*.

`boitecoloriee` is one of those environments. It typesets its contents in a gray background color inside a framed box.

With smaller fonts the lines typeset with this environment are cut in its bottom, as can be seen with the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{boites,boites_exemples}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{boitecoloriee}
  \lipsum[131]
\end{boitecoloriee}

\footnotesize

\begin{boitecoloriee}
  \lipsum[131]
\end{boitecoloriee}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: demonstration of the problem with the boitecoloriee environment]

Notice how the second box has defective lines.

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Would you know from where one can obtain the package `maboites.sty`? A separate comment: the `boites` package seems to be well more than 10 years old, and figuring out some of its functionality may be difficult to achieve at this point. Have you considered trying out the `mdframed` package instead? From your description (and from what I can tell is provided by `boites.sty`) it would appear that the functionality provided by the `mdframed` package (or its precursor, the `framed` package) is perfectly suited to meeting your needs.

Comment: @Mico `maboites.sty` is an unpublished package I have written that implements a new and more flexible environment using `boites`. It is not needed in this example, so it can be removed, and I am just going to do that.

Comment: @Mico In fact I have tried `boites`, `framed` and `mdframed` as options for framed boxes that can break across pages. I need such feature in a new package (`pygmentex`) I am writing to highlight source code using [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), similar to [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted), but more flexible and efficient. When I tried them, `boites` was my choice because it had less restrictions (for instance, it can be used in the `multicol` environment). But `mdframed` is getting better and I am considering switching to it.

Comment: Well, good luck with creating your package and with implementing some of the needed functionality via the `mdframed` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a fix to this issue: add the following line

```
\splittopskip\z@
```

just before the line

```
\baselineskip\z@
```

in the definition of `\endbreakbox` in `boites.sty`

The `\splittopskip` parameter specifies the glue that TeX inserts at the top of a box
resulting from a `\vsplit`. `\splittopskip` plays the same role that
`\topskip` plays for a page.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a bug in `boites.sty` that makes wrong assumptions about how to paint the background line by line. Indeed, if you say

```
\footnotesize

\begin{boitecoloriee}\baselineskip=12pt
  \lipsum[131]
\end{boitecoloriee}
```

the lines are not cut. So it's just that when the following line is typeset, it's assumed to be too high and it covers part of the line above.

Comment: I have contacted Vincent Zoonekynd, the author of `boites`, and he told me: _I no longer maintain that package, but since it is free software, you can modify it_. I think I have a fix for this issue (and others). What is the procedure in this case to update the package in CTAN?